# Error on gcloud artifact registry: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Maven config is not supported for format "DOCKER"

Tags: docker, maven, gcloud

I am trying to create an artifact using gcloud artifact registry and I ran the `gcloud init` command which was fine and then I ran the following command

`(venv) PS C:\Users\abc\Python VS code projects\project-name\server> gcloud artifacts repositories create repo-name --repository-format=docker --location=us-central1 --description="Docker repo description"`

in doing so I came across the following error

`ERROR: (gcloud.artifacts.repositories.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Maven config is not supported for format "DOCKER"`

I have been using the same list of gcloud commands for creating artifact registries and using them and many other apis on google cloud console for some time but I have not come across this error. I have tried googling it but no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Also my Docker file:

````
# run command to install all dependencies
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn flask_wtf pyrebase4 firebase_admin httplib2==0.15.0 pycryptodome==3.10.1 
# RUN pip install google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2 google-api-python-client

# now to copy our sourcre code to a folder in the container
COPY src/ app/
# and set this container folder to working directory
WORKDIR /app
# here set environment variable for a port which we set in app.run command in app.py
ENV PORT 8080
# run a command for gunicorn where we bind the ports, 
# set workers to 1, 
# set threads to 8,
# bind the app 
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:app```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem [here on github](https://github.com/google/app-reporting-pack). It does not say what the reason for the problem was but the solution was to update gcloud components.
I updated my Cloud SDK CLI by running following command in administrator mode.

```
gcloud components update
```